# how to get serial data from Bluetooth in unity 3d?

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, serial-port

i want to develop such application which will get serial data from my Bluetooth module UC-05 in unity 3d. I have code in java it works but i don't know how to integrate it in unity.

Answer (score 0):

This is something no one will do for you here but I will give you information required to do it yourself.

You need to convert the Java Bluetooth code into functions. For example, `bluetoothInit()`, `bluetoothConnect()`, `bluetoothSend()`, `bluetoothReceive()`, `bluetoothDisconnect()`, `bluetoothClose()`. Then compile it into a plugin (**jar** or **aar**) file. You can now call the functions from Unity C#.

Links on how to call Java functions from C# in Unity. I suggest you follow the first link.

http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/creating-a-native-android-plugin-for-unity3d/

http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/